# How to filter out by class and attribute value?

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery 1.4.3

I have several input that look like this:

```
 <input type='checkbox' id='1' class='Product' comp='1'>
 <input type='checkbox' id='2' class='Product' comp='1'>
 <input type='checkbox' id='3' class='Product' comp='1'>
 <input type='checkbox' id='4' class='Product' comp='2'>
 <input type='checkbox' id='5' class='Product' comp='2'>
 <input type='checkbox' id='6' class='Product' comp='2'>
```

If a box with the Product class is clicked I want to get its comp value and uncheck the other boxes that have a different comp value.

Normally, I would loop through and check each comp value and then uncheck where necessary, like this pseudo code:

```
ThisComp == 1 // comp value of checkbox that was just clicked
$(".Product").each(function() {
     var Comp $(this).attr("comp");
     if (ThisComp != Comp) {
         // $(this).attr("checked", false);
     }
});
```

I am wondering if there is a way to filter using the comp value in the selector, such as this pseudo code:

```
$(".Product comp=2").attr("checked", false);
```

The goal here is to uncheck any box that has a different comp value than the one clicked in an efficient way.

Comment: `id` values should not start with a number.

Comment: You might want to rename that attribute to `data-comp`. Data-attributes are automatically bound to `element.dataset` and jQuery's `.data()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

```
$(".Product[comp!='2']").attr("checked", false);
```

Comment: I think you should remove the space, or it will look for a descendant element.

Comment: Since the code is located inside the click handler, we can expect the `this` value to reference one of the check-boxes. Therefore, a global page-wide query for `.Product` elements is not a sensible solution.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas With the details provided I think this answers the question posed.  Your answer assumes that the checkboxes are inside of some sort of wrapper.  If there is in fact a wrapper, that can be used to improve performance.

Comment: @JamesMontagne A wrapper is not needed. As I said, since we're inside a click handler, the `this` value can be used to select the other check-boxes. I understand that your answer is correct - my comment was meant to note a best practice. The use of page-wide queries should be minimized (by providing context).

Comment: @ŠimeVidas A wrapper is required. What if the checkboxes are spread throughout the page with no common ancestor other than the body?  How does `this` help?  I try not to assume without stating my assumptions.

Comment: @JamesMontagne OP's code shows that the check-boxes are siblings.

Comment: But it's clearly not really the code.  He just has a line of checkboxes with no labels?

Comment: @JamesMontagne Well, we can either assume they're siblings (and leave it to the OP to update his question if that's not the case), or we can anticipate a common ancestor and use it to select the check-boxes. However, either way, doing a page-wide `$('.Product')` query is not the optimal solution. I just wanted to point that out.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
$( '#boxes' ).delegate('input:checkbox', 'click', function () {
    var comp = +$( this ).attr( 'comp' );
    $( this ).siblings().not( '[comp="' + comp + '"]' ).prop( 'checked', false );
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BMtTy/

---

Or with data-attributes:

```
$( '#boxes' ).delegate('input:checkbox', 'click', function () {
    var comp = +$( this ).data( 'comp' );
    $( this ).siblings().not( '[data-comp="' + comp + '"]' ).prop( 'checked', false );
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BMtTy/1/

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
$('.Product[comp="2"]').removeAttr("checked");
```

**UPDATE**

```
var comp = $(this).attr("comp");
$('.Product[comp="' + comp + '"]').removeAttr("checked");
```

Answer (score 1):

It's actually quite easy.  However, it is invalid to create custom attributes without using data-*. Use `data-comp` instead.  Another small note, cache your selection and filter it for added performance. I recommend something like this:

```
var $productChecks = $('.Product');
$productChecks.click(function() {
    var compValue = $(this).attr('data-comp');
    $productChecks
        // Uncheck boxes that don't have the same comp value
        // Since checked is a boolean attribute, use prop to set
        // Quote attribute value in selectors
        .filter('[data-comp!="' + compValue + '"]').prop('checked', false).end()
        // If desired, make sure the ones that have the same value are checked
        .not(this).filter('[data-comp="' + compValue + '"]').prop('checked', true);
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/prop

Comment: I recommend event delegation (since we have multiple elements of the same class which share the same event handler).

Comment: I think event delegation would be more appropriate if there were more than 6 checkboxes. It helps with initial execution time, but is slower than a directly bound handler, but then again, the difference is negligible either way.

Comment: I don't see why it would be slower. Why do you think that?

Comment: Can you provide some references to using data-*?

Comment: @EvikJames Read on HTML5Doctor: http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/

Comment: Thanks! I actually found some stuff yesterday and got schooled a bit. I will check out your link.  Thanks for being proactive with your answer.

Comment: As I said, the difference is negligible, but I'll explain. It is slower because instead of the browser firing jQuery's directly bound handler then jQuery firing any of its handlers immediately, the event is allowed to bubble up once. After the bubble, jQuery will test all children for matching selectors then fire any necessary handlers on those matching elements.  So you see, there are more steps when firing.  Event delegation helps a lot when you want to bind the same handlers to many elements (can save you very large loops), but it doesn't do much for you when there aren't a lot of elements.